# Does Julia use SIMD instructions for broadcast operations?

Tags: julia

I see `@simd` can be used to vectorize `for` loops. How about for `broadcast()`?

1. Will `broadcast(f,A)` translate to SIMD instructions of `f` operating on the elements `A`?
2. Will multiple instances of `f` be sent to multiple threads?

Comment: Check `@code_native`. It should, but whether it will depends on if you use the default -O3 compilation and have rebuilt the system image.

Comment: Note that there is a misconception in this question. SIMD has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: Correct. I'm curious if either/both occur.

Comment: You can have julia use threads, just check out http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing/#multi-threading-experimental 
Check out the instructions at http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/sysimg/
to rebuild the system image as Chris mentions, it's quite straightforward.

Comment: Cross-posted question: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/does-julia-use-simd-instructions-for-broadcast-operations/2492/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/does-julia-use-simd-instructions-for-broadcast-operations/2492/6):

Julia 0.5 will automatically use SIMD instructions if LLVM decides to auto-vectorize the underlying `broadcast()` loop. There is currently no way to explicitly demand this.

The underlying loop will use a single thread.